# How to find airline booking code before buying the ticket

Tags: tickets, airlines

Airlines usually have booking codes attached to the class: for example Economy (Y), Economy (T) etc. Is there a way to find this code before buying a ticket?

Any help will be much appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** This is not for a particular airline but for common travel booking websites like Expedia, CheapTickets, Orbitz etc.

Comment: Not sure if there's a 100% consistent way, and it depends how you are booking it. In my experience, if you are booking with the airline, some show it on their website, and others don't.

Comment: What airline is this for?  There is some commonality but types are not universal.

Comment: I don't think that booking websites assign these.  Airlines do.

Comment: @Karlson: I agree with you - the airlines assign them. But is it possible to find out what is the code for a ticket I'm about to buy. I called customer service of one such site and I was told that they don't have the information.

Comment: @KL Would it make a difference?

Comment: @Karlson I think that it helps to compare the value of the tickets offered on different websites.

Comment: @KL You can use Skyscanner or Kayak for that..  It will give you best price for the exact same fare offered.

Comment: @Karlson These services compare only price but not value. They don't tell you that by paying a little extra you can get extra leg room for that long overseas flight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that airline booking codes are not generally available. This is the information that I was able to gather so far:

1. The reservation systems of some airline companies display booking codes (e.g. Lufthansa).
2. Some travel booking websites display it as well (e.g. Expedia: click on the "Show Flight Details" link)
3. I tried to call customer service of a travel booking website and asked for the booking code of a specific flight but they told me that only the airlines can give it.